# Is there an easy way to remove the white spaces in list items

Tags: python, string

I;m trying to split a string using a delimiter and store them in the form of dictionary.

When i use split, it returns a list in which there are white spaces.

I would like to know if we can remove white spaces during the split operation itself or should i have to do something like below to get rid of the white spaces?

the code that i have written is as follows:

```
word ='SAMPLE TEXT               :HELLO                '
k,v = words.split(':')
k = k.strip()
v = v.strip()
D[k] = v
```

kindly let me know

Comment: You might want to enforce a single split by using [`.split(':', maxsplit=1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), otherwise you could get an error unpacking too many values.

Comment: Ok.. make sense. will modify in my script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using unbound method [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> word ='SAMPLE TEXT               :HELLO                '
>>> k, v = map(str.strip, word.split(':'))
>>> k
'SAMPLE TEXT'
>>> v
'HELLO'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> word ='SAMPLE TEXT               :HELLO                '
>>> import re
>>> k,v = re.split('\s*:\s*',word.strip())
>>> k,v
('SAMPLE TEXT', 'HELLO')
```

Comment: I'm new to reg ex.. The above regex matches only trailing while spaces. how to i match the leading while spaces as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> word ='SAMPLE TEXT               :HELLO                '
>>> k,v=[str.strip(x) for x in word.split(':')]
>>> k
'SAMPLE TEXT'
>>> v
'HELLO'
```